# Using Underscore _.debounce() to trigger a single event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following function that is being called from a keyPress listener on an input text field. The _.debounce() is working correctly, except instead of only firing the function 1 time after the time period, it is firing as many times as the keyPress event happened.

```
console.log("Pre Debounce");
var debounced = _.debounce(function() {
    console.log("Field updated!");
}, 2000);

debounced();
```

Is there a way to limit the _.debounce function to only fire 1 time after the time period?

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you are constructing the debounce function each time inside the event. If that's your case then take your debounce function outside the event response code. As far as I know the debounced function should be generated only one time and then be called multiple times.

Another thing that could go weird is when you are making an async call (ex. with an ajax autocomplete) and it takes more than your wait time for debounce then the requests could fire later making appear that debouncing is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your debounce function is taking longer to execute than the user to type. In this case, you want to make sure that you prevent double debouncing by passing in a third argument (immediate) as true.

The debounce function signature is: `_.debounce(function, wait, [immediate])`

So change the code to:

```
console.log("Pre Debounce");
var debounced = _.debounce(function() {
    console.log("Field updated!");
}, 2000, true);

debounced();
```

Comment: I've tried this and it causes the debouce to not function correctly and fire every time the keyPress fires. I'm not sure as to why that is the case, but that is why I did not have the "immediate" option set as true.

Comment: If it doesn't fire every time when you pass in true for the third parameter, then the problem is definitely that your debounce callback is taking longer than it takes the user to type the next character. Do you mind sharing what the callback does? Perhaps we can help make it faster.